# Docker-compose elastic stack no container tags

Tags: docker, docker-compose, logstash, elastic-stack

I have a setup with docker-compose and the elastic stack. My 'main' container is running a Django application (there are some more containers for metrics, certificates, and so on).

The logging itself works with this setup but I have no container labels or tags in Kibana. So I can't differentiate between logs from different containers (except when I know what I'm looking for).

How do I configure logstash or logspout to label or tag all logs with the container where they're from? In the best case tagging container image and container id.

I tried to add a label to the container but that didn't change anything. I also tried specified logging, with driver syslog and a tag, but that didn't work either.

I guess I have to make a specific logstash config and do some stuff there?

Below is my current docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'

services:
    # django container
    web:
        build: .
        command: gunicorn backend.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8001 --log-level debug
        restart: unless-stopped
        container_name: web
        depends_on:
            - logspout
        expose:
            - 8001
        env_file:
            - ./environments/web.test.env
        image: mycontainer
        labels:
            container: "web"
            com.example.service: "web"

    logspout:
        image: gliderlabs/logspout:v3.2.11
        command: 'udp://logstash:5000'
        restart: unless-stopped
        links:
            - logstash
        volumes:
            - '/var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock'
        depends_on:
            - elasticsearch
            - logstash
            - kibana
        
    logstash:
        image: logstash:7.9.1
        restart: unless-stopped
        environment:
        - STDOUT=true
        links:
        - elasticsearch
        expose:
        - 5000
        depends_on:
        - elasticsearch
        - kibana
        command: 'logstash -e "input { udp { port => 5000 } } output { elasticsearch { hosts => elasticsearch } }"'

    kibana:
        image: kibana:7.9.1
        restart: unless-stopped
        links:
        - elasticsearch
        environment:
        - ELASTICSEARCH_URL=http://elasticsearch:9200
        ports:
        - 5601:5601
        depends_on:
        - elasticsearch

    elasticsearch:
        image: elasticsearch:7.9.1
        restart: unless-stopped
        ports:
        - 9200:9200
        - 9300:9300
        environment:
            - node.name=elasticsearch
            - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
            - cluster.initial_master_nodes=elasticsearch
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I'm really inexperienced with the elastic stack, but I got it right.

Indeed you have to provide a logstash config with filter, at least that's how I got it working. Additionally, I had to switch from UDP to just syslog in logspout, I guess the udp connection didn't forward all it got (for example the docker image).

Here are my configurations that work (there are definitely some improvements to do).

logstash.conf

```
input {
  syslog {
      port => 5000
      type => "docker"
  }
}

filter {
  grok {
    match => { "message" => "%{SYSLOG5424PRI}%{NONNEGINT:ver} +(?:%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:ts}|-) +(?:%{HOSTNAME:service}|-) +(?:%{NOTSPACE:containerName}|-) +(?:%{NOTSPACE:proc}|-) +(?:%{WORD:msgid}|-) +(?:%{SYSLOG5424SD:sd}|-|) +%{GREEDYDATA:msg}" }
  }
  syslog_pri { }
}

output {
  elasticsearch { hosts => "elasticsearch" }
  stdout {codec => rubydebug}
}
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'

services:
    web:
        build: .
        command: gunicorn backend.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8001 --log-level debug
        restart: unless-stopped
        container_name: web
        depends_on:
            - logspout
        image: myimage
        expose:
            - 8001
        env_file:
            - ./environments/web.test.env

        labels:
            container: "web"
            com.example.service: "web"

    logspout:
        image: gliderlabs/logspout:v3.2.11
        command: 'syslog://logstash:5000'
        restart: unless-stopped
        links:
            - logstash
        volumes:
            - '/var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock'
        depends_on:
            - elasticsearch
            - logstash
            - kibana
        
    logstash:
        image: logstash:7.9.1
        restart: unless-stopped
        environment:
            - LOGSPOUT=ignore
        links:
            - elasticsearch
        depends_on:
            - elasticsearch
            - kibana
        volumes:
            - ./containers/logstash/logstash.conf:/usr/share/logstash/pipeline/logstash.conf

    kibana:
        image: kibana:7.9.1
        restart: unless-stopped
        links:
            - elasticsearch
        environment:
            - LOGSPOUT=ignore
            - ELASTICSEARCH_URL=http://elasticsearch:9200
        ports:
            - 5601:5601
        depends_on:
            - elasticsearch

    elasticsearch:
        image: elasticsearch:7.9.1
        restart: unless-stopped
        ports:
        - 9200:9200
        - 9300:9300
        environment:
            - LOGSPOUT=ignore
            - node.name=elasticsearch
            - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
            - cluster.initial_master_nodes=elasticsearch
```